# Resource path parameter not passed to Route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Somehow the parameter `user_id` is not being passed to my UserIndexRoute. What could be going wrong?

The error I'm getting as a result is

> Assertion Failed: You may not pass `undefined` as id to the store's
>   find method

- The request is /users/1
- A user with id 1 does exist in its model fixtures
- There are no other errors in my app, the users route is working and showing the fixturedata for user

**router.js**

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: DaappEmber2ENV.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users', function(){
    this.resource('user', { path:'/:user_id' }, function(){
        this.route('edit');
    });
    this.route('create');
  });
});
```

export default Router;

**routes/user/index.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        Ember.Logger.debug('Params for user/index route:', params);
        return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've defined a dynamic slug, user_id on the users route, but then you are trying to access it on the usersindex route.  Child route's don't inherit params from their parent resources.  Create a users route and it will be available there.

Comment: Thank you. It was confusing for me as I just started with Ember.

For everyone else. If you define a route like `User` with `path: '/:user_id'` a route called UserIndexRoute will be the destination route. But still the UserRoute is the route which is directly linked to 'User' and therefor will be the correct route to catch the dynamic slug `user_id`

Comment: @Kingpin2k, can you elaborate on this, please?  __Child route's don't inherit params from their parent resources.__  Is this in the documentation?  If so, I must read it for the hundred first time!  ;-)  In my case, using the example above, I'm unable to pass the params from the 'user' route to the 'edit' route when it is nested.

Comment: I think the more appropriate statement would be, is their documentation showing that sub routes get the parameters of their parent routes.  If you have a child route, you can just use `this.modelFor` to grab the parent's resource.  http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor